# Ubuntu 14.04 - Processor details is empty

Tags: 14.04, cpu, arm, cpuinfo

while installing ubuntu via JetPack [ it's Nvidia Jetson TX1 embedded board - supports full OS installation ] 
the processor details as shown in the image below is empty.
the OS keeps hanging and restarting.

[image]

using command **lscpu**

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) command `lscpu`.

Comment: @ByteCommander updated as required

Comment: Thanks, but you should paste terminal output as plain text (formatted as code) for better readability and to make searching for it possible. And what exactly would you want, what is your aim?

Comment: @ByteCommander i'm wondering why is that happening , the OS keeps hanging and it keep restarting.

Comment: This, however, is a different issue and probably has nothing to do with the lack of CPU information. You should open a new question and describe in detail all symptoms you see there. You can add a link to this question if you think they are related.